# Upload additional side artifact to existing artifact

Tags: java, maven, artifactory, nexus

Say I have a jar artifact in my repository, which means I have a pom, a jar, and two side artifacts with "sources" and "javadoc" classifier.

Assume now I want to add an additional side artifact with "xy" classifier. It would be straight forward in the build itself (so that the `deploy` goal uploads all of them), but is it possible to just add a side artifact to an existing artifact?

I am using Nexus 2 at the moment, but the question is more general because the resulting construction should also work in Nexus 3 or Artifactory.

Comment: I bet it would not be allowed cause a release is immutable...and it shouldn't matter if Nexus 2 or 3...

Comment: Have you tried using the [deploy plugin with a classifier](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploying-with-classifiers.html)?

Comment: @heenenee I haven't tried anything - for a thorough test, I would need to have Nexus 2, Nexus 3 and Artifactory running, which I do not have.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible in Nexus, because you would be uploading a new file. Or [speaking in Nexus 3 language](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Components,+Repositories,+and+Repository+Formats) you would be uploading a new asset to an existing component.

I'm not sure, but I assume it would be the same case with Artifactory.